# How to reference resource from Resources file

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a bunch of messages in a Constants file that I want to convert all string constants for messages displayed to users to be moved to a localized/globalization resource file.

I created a Resources.resx file and I'm trying to figure out how to reference a resource in a controller. For example this resource in my Resources.resx file

```
internal static string ItemUpdateFailed {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("ItemUpdateFailed", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

I want to reference it in a controller action to replace the bolded reference to the string constant in the method below. How do I reference the resource above in the method below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var itemIndexViewModel = new ItemIndexViewModel();
        try
        {
            _mapper.Map(await _itemService.GetItemAsync(ItemStatus.Active, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true), itemIndexViewModel.Items);
        }
        catch
        {                
            **TempData.Put(TempDataKey.Item.UPDATE_MESSAGE, StatusMessageModel.Create(Constants.Item.TO_CREATE_UPDATE_FAIL));**
        }
        return View(itemIndexViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: According to your description, I think perhaps you want to make the app's content localizable in the controller action method, right? If that is the case, you could consider to use [IStringLocalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.istringlocalizer) to localize the content. Check [Make the app's content localizable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#make-the-apps-content-localizable-2).

Comment: I want to be able to create an abstraction so I don't have to call the Resource in the controller. Not sure how to do that. Any ideas?